# Using C# regex to get any words after one or more "\" characters

Tags: c#, regex, backslash

Edit: It turns out my code below does work, just not when entering the values from the debugger. The single backslash example failed when entered from the debugger because the single backslash was treated as an escape character rather than a backslash.

I'm trying to get a user alias from a string that may be any one of the following inputs:

1. alias
2. domain\alias
3. domain\\alias

My C# regex pattern looks like this:

```
string pattern = @"(.*\\)(.*)";
```

And I'm doing this in code:

```
string alias = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$2", RegexOptions.None);
```

This returns:

1. alias
2. domain\alias
3. alias

Note that it does not work for #2 (with a single '\'). What's the solution to make this work?

Here is the exact code of the method (sorry if this doesn't format nicely):

```
private string[] CreateEmailArrayFromString(string p)
{
    string[] address = new string[] { string.Empty };
    if (p != null)
    {
        address = p.Split(new char[] { ';', ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
        {
            if (address[i].Contains("@") == false)
            {
                string pattern = @"(.*\\)(.*)";
                address[i] = Regex.Replace(address[i], pattern, "$2", RegexOptions.None);
                address[i] = string.Concat(address[i].Trim(), "@mycompany.com");
            }
        }
    }
    return address;
}
```

Comment: I just ran this, and I'm getting `"alias"` for all three. Is there something else to the code?

Comment: Have you considered using `input.Split('\\').Last()` instead of a regex?

Comment: As @Jacob said, this is working (switch to "context" tab): [regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(.*%5c%5c)(.*)&i=alias%0d%0adomain%5calias%0d%0adomain%5c%5calias%0d%0a&r=%242)

Comment: Is this code correct? It can't really be `.\*` - that wouldn't work at all...

Comment: Your new snippet has `@"(.*\\\\)(.\*)"` instead of what you originally posted. That will only work for a double backslash. If you replace that with your originally posted regex, it should work.

Comment: it's the formatting. It should be as my original post.

Comment: stuggling with the formatting. it's fixed now.

Comment: Even with your new snippet, I'm getting the correct results. For example `@"domain\foo, domain\\foo, foo"` is returning `{ "foo@mycompany.com", "foo@mycompany.com", "foo@mycompany.com" }`

Comment: Maybe the input isn't what you think it is?

Comment: @Jacob, I think you are right. I've been adding strings via the debugger and my single backslash is probably 'escaping' the next character rather than being treated as a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

This code *does* work:

```
string pattern = @"(.*\\)(.*)";
string alias = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$2", RegexOptions.None);
```

It probably won't work if the input is coming from the debugger. That is what was happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a LINQ solution that works for all three cases:

```
string str = @"domain\\alias";
string str2 = @"domain\alias";
string str3 = @"alias";

string res = new string(str.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => c != '\\').Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: I get an error on address[i].Reverse <-- not recognized method on the array.

Comment: Why? Now your code doesn't work for the character: "é", not to mention Hebrew or Arabic characters with punctuation. [Jon skeet and tony the pony will explain](https://vimeo.com/7403673). You didn't need to care about any of this. Why reverse the string?